# How to Copy specific column values from one excel file to another?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I'm trying to copy specific column values from one excel file to the other.  This is what I've tried.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\A.xls")
Set objWorkbook2 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\C.xls")

Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
objWorksheet.Activate

Set objRange = objWorksheet.Range("A:Q").EntireColumn
objRange.Copy

Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets(1)
objWorksheet.Activate

objWorksheet.Range("A:B").EntireColumn.Copy objWorksheet2.Paste
objWorksheet2.Range ("A1")

objWorksheet.Columns("Q").EntireColumn.Copy objWorksheet2.Paste
objWorksheet2.Range ("C1")

objWorkbook2.Save 
objWorkbook2.Close
```

My doubt is, the column Q contains formula.  So, when column is copied, only formula is copied but not the values.  **Please help to copy the values in the cell but not the formula.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You should get in the habit of declaring your variables (as well as formatting your code).

```
Sub x()

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\A.xls")
Set objWorkbook2 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\C.xls")

Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Set objRange = objWorksheet.Range("A:Q").EntireColumn
objRange.Copy 'not sure what this does

Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets(1)

objWorksheet.Range("A:B").Copy objWorksheet2.Range("A1")

objWorksheet.Columns("Q").EntireColumn.Copy
objWorksheet2.Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlValues

objWorkbook2.Save
objWorkbook2.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code.  I don't know why **objWorksheet2.Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlValues** is not working for me. but objWorksheet2.Range("C1").PasteSpecial -4163 works.  Any idea?   Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is because `xlValues` would normally be defined as a constant at the beginning of the VBS file - it is missing from this snippet.